# Run a local dll file, select printer etc... Alternative to NPAPI

Tags: web-services, web, npapi, google-nativeclient, ppapi

I´m looking for a sustainable solution when it comes to communicating with hardware on a local machine. I´ve been reading about NPAPI but unfortunately it is being phased out.

I would like to run things like silent printing from a website. The system shall be able to decide if it shall print to a receipt printer or a A4-printer. At the moment I need to set a default printer but I would the system to determine which printer that shall be used.

I would also like to run a dll file that exists locally on the users machine.

Are there any other solutions for my problem?

Kind regards / H

Answer (score 2):

For hardware support, have a look at [chrome.usb, chrome.bluetooth, chrome.sockets, and chrome.serial](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index.html). These APIs are available to Chrome Apps.

"Running a DLL" doesn't quite makes sense unless you mean DllRegisterServer or some other executable that loads the DLL into its process space. Either way, [Native Messaging is your friend](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging). But note that you're going to need administrative access to the target machines; that's the only way to get Chrome to run arbitrary native executables.

As for specific library functionality, have you tried simply building the DLL as a NaCl module? There's a [huge number of common libraries](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/PortList) that are successfully running under NaCl with minimal porting effort, which bodes well for your DLL doing the same (assuming you have the source).

I have no idea what you mean by "sustainable," so I'm not trying to answer that part of your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By sustainable I mean a solution that is not phased out like NPAPI.

Comment: @Sowbug: you wrote "But note that you're going to need administrative access to the target machines; that's the only way to get Chrome to run arbitrary native executables." 

Could you clarify this? or maybe link to some documentation about it? Does this imply that native-messaging will not work unless run on a  machine with admin-rights?

Comment: @hgerdin how did you solve this? Was NaCL or PPAPI the solution? My requirement is similar. I need to choose a printer based on the configuration from DB. Moreover like your requirement i need to be able to do this from a webapp and not from a Chrome app.